# Missing resource bundle com.adobe.flex.framework:playerglobal:rb.swc:ko_KR:4.5.1.21328

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flex-mojos

facing a issue while creating locale file with maven build for Korean locale.
rest of language resource bundle get created properly only Korean locale giving problem.
the following error occur.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-RC2:compile-swf (default-compile-swf) on project
---: Execution default-compile-swf of goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.0-RC2:compile-swf failed: Missing 
resource bundle 'com.adobe.flex.framework:flash-integration:rb.swc:ko_KR:4.5.1.21328

Comment: Check in your SDK folder to see if the locale files exist for the Korean language at:  `/SDK_PATH/frameworks/locale/ko_KR`

Answer (score 0):

- For this I have bundled required swc in my package and called same from maven build.